# Pass Build inputs from Jenkins to python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and Python. I have jenkings test build Project with build parameters. Below is the screen shot for reference.

[ScreenShot of build Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCoU8.png)

I need to Pass this inputs to python script "test.py"

My execute command is looks like below:

```
    /usr/bin/python2.7 /scripts/test.py
```

test.py script:

```
  import time
  import os
  input1 = os.getenv("input1")
  input2 = os.getenv("input2")
  Dropdown = os.getenv("Dropdown1")
  Dropdown2 = os.getenv("Dropdown2")
  print input1
  print input2
  print Dropdown
  print Dropdown2
```

Console output:

```
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/workspace/Inputs-Test
[Inputs-Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/temp/jenkins3261310337115825812.sh
+ /usr/bin/python2.7 /project/test.py
None
None
None
None
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: As stated below on the answer comment, I've revised the getenv to match your parameter naming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since those parameters are part of the environment of the Jenkins created process you are always able to access them in the following way.

```
import os
input1 = os.getenv("Input1")
input2 = os.getenv("input2")
Dropdown = os.getenv("Dropdown")
Dropdown2 = os.getenv("dropdown2")
```

Now set those in your setupClass or your test setup method.

Comment: @ llhicas Getting none results

Comment: try the following before the test.py command

echo $Input1

for example and check if its available, if it is present there, your problem might be elsewhere in python test

And you are getting none results because I realized you have some variables with UpperCase and some with lowerCase

Comment: Edited the answer to have the same environment variables as in your screenshot